# Making a ridge for a tile roof - Any cheap way?

Tags: roof

I'm making a shed, with a roof made of cement tiles. I'm trying to be as cheap as possible, but still making it as nice as I can. Most materials are salvaged from here or there, or bought second-hand.

I managed to find exactly the tiles model I wanted, for cheap, but it is very difficult to find the corresponding ridge tiles this way. And those are very expensive if I buy them new (to get the 11 ridge tiles I need, I'll have to pay more than the price I paid for the ~140 standard tiles I got - call me stingy, but that annoys me).

So, I was wondering if there were any cheap way to solve this. Here are some options I was considering:

- Making a dome all along the ridge, just with cement mortar. But I'm afraid it will crack. And it will probably be a bit difficult to have a nice-looking result.
- Using different kind of tiles. I can easily find some standard curved-shape clay tiles ([something like this](https://inspectapedia.com/roof/0039ss.jpg)) for cheap, and seal them with cement. To me, it looks similar to the ridge tiles, but I'm not sure it can be used as such.
- Something else?

Here is the details of what I currently have:

[image]

And, for information, a [link to the documentation](http://monier.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/PLEIN-CIEL.pdf) of the tile model I used (sorry, it's in French).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think standard half-round tiles, if large enough, would be your best bet, other than "having saved all this money on the roof tiles, I can afford to put on the correct ridge tiles, even if it feels like a lot of money, comparatively."

Third way would be casting your own.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, since the standard tiles are cheap and available, you could use a circular saw with a masonry blade and cut those; leaving just the half-round part.

Then you could start at each end, placing them toward the middle of the ridge, each one resting on the end of the one before to give a bit of slope. Each half-round piece would have to overhang the roof tiles of course, which might mean moving those up farther toward the ridge.

You might consider drilling to provide a way to nail/spike them down, or consider using mortar to set them. The center seam could be capped/covered with a short one mortared down.

I do not see sheathing or roof paper... wouldn't it be a good idea to cover the roof with a sheathing (plywood or OSB) covered with waterproof paper, then attach the cleats and tiles?

Comment: I don't think sheathing is necessary. First, this is just a shed, so I can be more lax on the rules than for a house. And even for my house (which isn't very old: 25 years), there is no sheathing. Not even a rain screen. It probably isn't necesary in the region I live in.

Comment: Yeah ok, and now that I think about it if you used the (cut) roof tiles for the ridge it would be better to just line them up flat across the ridge,then cap each joint with a smaller cut piece mortared into place.

Comment: I think Jimmy has an acceptable answer but many years ago I did a few tile roofs and we used lead for coverage at the ridge Y's, not sure what sheet lead cost today but back then it was very cheap and it lasts.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself, but I have seen many roofs like this is South America where tiles are turned long ways and placed along the ridge. I'm not sure what the width of the tiles are, but just cut them to the width that covers the 12cm gap. The edges of the ridge tiles should rest on top of the other tiles. I'm no artist, but maybe this drawing will help explain what I mean.  [image: tileridge]

**Edit:** This is one photo I found. This has a single 1/2 oval shape, but they are common in multiple 1/2 ovals as well. [image: tileroofhonduras]

Comment: I'm surprised. How does the water trapped in the middle of the tile escapes, if there is no slope along the ridge line, then? I'm afraid there would be leaks between each tiles.

Comment: Again, I have never done this, but the ones I have seen are mortared in place. I will attach a photo of one that may help illustrate.